# How to pin a layout inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to create a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with three elements, where only one is marked with `pin` and the others with `parallax`.

However all elements are always collapsed

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_wave" />

        <com.example.ui.StatementHeaderView
            android:id="@+id/statementHeaderView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_statement"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The `toolbar_statement` is a simple layout the *replaces* Android toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_main_toolbar"
    android:background="@color/toolbarStatement">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/height_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/slider_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/nav_balance_sheet" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_calendar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/height_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If `toolbar_statement` is replaced by `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, the element is correctly pinned.

Does it means that only `Toolbar` elements may be pinned?

Comment: Is the `AppBarLayout`'s height really `wrap_content` while the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s height is `match_parent`? That's a combination that won't work

Answer (score 0):

In [the developer guide for `<include>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Include), there's a note at the end of the "Use the `<include>` tag" section:

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any `android:layout_*` attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the `<include/>` tag. For example:
>
> ```
> <include android:id="@+id/news_title"
>      android:layout_width="match_parent"
>      android:layout_height="match_parent"
>      layout="@layout/title"/>
> ```
>
> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the `<include>` tag, you must override both `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

Your include tag doesn't have either layout_height or layout_width specified, but you're trying to override a layout parameter (collapseMode). I suspect the problem will be fixed if you add these two attributes to your include tag.

Comment: I've replaced the include by the whole layout as you previously suggested, but the problem continues. I've also tried using a simple `View` element, and the problem also occurs.

Comment: Could you add the source for your included layout to your question?